# parsing ints from an array mixed with strings and ints

Tags: java, parsing

I have a string that reads like this

```
"Anderson, T",CWS,SS,123,498,81,167,32,0,18,56,15,109,17,5,0.335,0.357,0.508,0.865
```

I need to extract each part. Ive already parsed the fist three string ("Anderson, T", CWS, SS) but now i need to extract 123 and im having some trouble doing it. The way I did it for the first three fields is i just used line.split

```
public static String parsePOS(String line) {
    String[] tokens = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
    return tokens[2];
}
```

But I cannot use line.split with an int array. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing different between `SS` and `123`, they are both just a sequence of characters in a string. If you want to get the `123` value as an `int` value, first get the text from `tokens[3]`, not `tokens[2]`, then convert the string value to an `int` value by calling `Integer.parseInt(s)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="\"Anderson, T\",CWS,SS,123,498,81,167,32,0,18,56,15,109,17,5,0.335,0.357,0.508,0.865";
        int x=Integer.parseInt(parsePOS(str));
        System.out.println(x);//123
        System.out.println(x+1);//124
    }
    public static String parsePOS(String line) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
        return tokens[3];
    }
}
```

Use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to parse an integer in `String` format.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it!